Problem with formatting the list of figures
The list problem

I had test the \usepackage{tocloft}, but causes this:


Help me please, I need to finish my thesis.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your screenshots show no code at all, and hence it's well-nigh impossible to perform a diagnosis of the situation. Please edit your query to show the code of a minimum working example, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}, that generates the problem you wish to fix.

Try with \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
